# I created a Tree class and a TreeNode class . However when i call the delete on the object , i get "free() : invalid size" on the output

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, tree

So I created this Tree Class , whose object would be a generic tree. For the nodes of this Tree , I also created a TreeNode class and whose object would serve as the nodes of my Tree Object. However when I call delete on the object of my Tree Class , After deleting all the nodes , in the end it gives free() : invalid size on the outpput.Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my destructor? Should i just have one destructor? or is there any solution to this? Kindly consider me naive and ignore some small mistakes or let me know so that I can correct them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class TreeNode{
    public:
        T data;
        vector<TreeNode *> children;
        
        TreeNode(T data){
            this -> data = data;
        }
        
        ~TreeNode(){
            for(int i = 0 ; i < children.size() ; i++)
                delete children[i];
        }
};

template <typename T>
class Tree{
  private:
    TreeNode<T> *root;
    
    
  public:
    Tree(){
        root = NULL;
    }
    
    ~Tree(){
        delete root;
    }
    
    
    void takeInput(){
        cout<<"Enter root data"<<endl;
        T rootData;
        cin>>rootData;
        
        TreeNode<T> *root = new TreeNode<T>(rootData);
        queue<TreeNode<T> *> q;
        
        q.push(root);
        while(!q.empty()){
            TreeNode<T> *front = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout<<"Enter child data for "<<front -> data<<endl;
            int childData;
            cin>>childData;
            while(childData != -1){
                TreeNode<T> *child = new TreeNode<T>(childData);
                front->children.push_back(child);
                q.push(child);
                cin>>childData;
            }
        }
        this -> root = root;
    }
    
    void print(){
        cout<<"Printing tree in level order form -: "<<endl;
        queue<TreeNode<T> *> q;
        q.push(root);
        while(!q.empty()){
            TreeNode<T> *front = q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout<<front -> data<<":";
            for(int i = 0 ; i < front -> children.size() ; i++){
                if(i == front -> children.size() - 1)
                    cout<<front->children[i]->data;
                else
                    cout<<front -> children[i] -> data<<",";
                q.push(front -> children[i]);
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
    
    
    
};


int main(){
    Tree<int> t1;
    t1.takeInput();
    t1.print();
    delete &t1;
}
```

Comment: why do you call `delete` ?

Comment: You must `delete` what you `new` (and `delete[]` what you `new[]`). But if you don't do `new` then you should not do `delete`. This should be part of every decent book, tutorial or class.

Comment: On another note I recommend you learn about *smart pointers* and get to know their ownership semantics. For example [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Don't pay any attention to the person that told you that `delete &t1;` would be a good idea. Get a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks a lot , i got the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

In the TreeNode destructor, remove the child vector. The child vector may contain pointers that have already been removed by the Tree destructor. This can lead to double free errors. To avoid this, either the Tree destructor must not delete child vectors, or the TreeNode destructor must not delete child pointers. I hope this may help.

Comment: It would be better to show some sample (corrected) code to illustrate what you describe.